# Why is AutoMapper enumerating an IEnumerable multiple times?

Tags: automapper

We ran in to performance issues and tracked it down to AutoMapper enumerating twice over an IEnumerable.
It's easily fixable on our side by simply feeding AutoMapper a List or Array, but I'm still curious if this is expected behavior.

The following minimal repro test fails::

```
[Test]
public void AutoMapper_Should_Not_Enumerate_Multiple_Times()
{
    var counter = 0;
    var values = Enumerable.Range(0, 3).Select(_ => counter++);
    var mapper = new Mapper(new MapperConfiguration(_ => { }));

    var dest= mapper.Map<int[]>(values);

    Assert.Equal(3, counter);
}
```

Result: Counter = 6, dest = [3,4,5], which means the IEnumerable is iterated twice and the second iteration is returned.

I tried debugging this in AutoMapper, but I only figured out that something was first calling Count() and then iterating:

[image]

[image]

Is this expected behavior? How or where is an IEnumerable mapped to an Array and why is Count() called before iterating?

Comment: Count is likely being called to [determine the size of the array](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/daf978fdd9057d1e5849334894aa493d66a7a045/src/AutoMapper/Mappers/ArrayMapper.cs#L45) needing to be allocated as the destination of the mapping

Comment: Try the [MyGet](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/The-MyGet-build.html) build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is implemented by the [ArrayMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/565c9634e2a0b487c9b25bca20f67a43e0ee06a3/src/AutoMapper/Mappers/ArrayMapper.cs#L25-L53) and the implementation is *functionally* this:

```cs
var count = source.Count();
var array = new TDestination[count];

int i = 0;
foreach (var item in source)
    array[i++] = newItemFunc(item, context);
return array;
```

Comment: This was already optimized and the next version will just call `ToArray` whenever possible.

Comment: I checked out the explicit_expand-branch and there the test is green https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/f5614efe38a4419baafe083633390da87d049996/src/AutoMapper/Mappers/CollectionMapper.cs#L136